# Appending C# Activity to a Java Activity in one Android App

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin

I am a C# programmer and my colleagues are Java programmers. We want to build Android Apps for mobile.

Is it possible to build an App with Activities built using C# (using Mono from Xamarin) and other activities built using Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent the question to Mono support staff and got the answer :

> yes you can create an app with both C# and Java via our binding
>   process. Please see the following link for more information on this
>   process: http://goo.gl/pneac

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to wrap Mono in Java, only the other way around. An app I am using provides an SMS interception activity that is supposed to open from a notification, and it drags entire Mono runtime with it. It would be cool to add a pure Java activity to a Mono app, but alas.